# fscanf doesn't read anything

Tags: c, file

i am trying to read integers from a file and fscanf doesn't work well with this code.

```
fp=fopen("record.dat","r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("Another reading error");
}
else
{
    printf("\nstarting to read\n");
    i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp)>0)
        printf("%d\n",temp);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

the file contains 10 numbers which are delimited by a new line character. This code doesn't produce or **print** anything. What is the problem with the code and pls help me with it.

**EDIT**
the access mode as **w+** or **r** isn't giving me a correct expected answer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY w+ is read write mode. what difference does it make? i tried with it also. and no difference in results.

Comment: I think different format in the file if you can't read in mode "r".

Comment: @max What difference it makes is the bit where `"w+"` truncates your file to 0 length, in which case any attempt to read something from the file before you write something first will fail to produce useful results.

Comment: Oh contents of the file already has been lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file as a writable file instead of readable.

You must change `"w+"` to `"r"`

`w+ The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.`

Comment: w+ is read write mode. what difference does it make? i tried with it also. and no difference in results.

Comment: Change the format string, you are not reading the newline. See my update. If the file is existing it is truncated, so it will be empty with `w+`

Comment: "%d\n" is required? I mean fscanf streams the data until it gets any white spaces right? And yes,thanks for the answer. I got the output. The file record.dat is not present in the same directory.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure now, it's been some time. I think your main problem was the w+ though. I remove the recommendation for the newline.

Answer (score 2):

`"w+"` actually opens file for reading and writing. However, file is truncated to `0` length.
That might be the cause of printing blank lines.
Try `"r+"` (opens the file for reading and writing, without truncation) or `"r"`.